# std::async([](){ std::cout<< "Hello "; }) build error

Tags: c++, build

[CppCon 2015: Detlef Vollmann “Executors for C++ - A Long Story ..."](https://youtu.be/sAJGoHN6Xx8?t=43s) starts off with this example:

```
std::async([](){ std::cout << "Hello "; });
std::async([](){ std::cout << "World!\n"; });
```

[C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) shows `std::async` is in `<future>` and `std::cout` is in `<iostream>`. What is missing to make the build work?

```
$ cat >hw.cpp <<EOF
> #include <iostream>
> int main(){
>     std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
> }
> EOF
$ clang++ -std=c++14 hw.cpp
$ ./a.out
Hello World!
$ cat >cppcon15.cpp <<EOF
> #include <future>
> #include <iostream>
> int main(){
>     std::async([](){ std::cout << "Hello "; });
>     std::async([](){ std::cout << "World!\n"; });
> }
> EOF
$ clang++ -std=c++14 cppcon15.cpp
/tmp/cppcon15-4f0a58.o: In function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_1 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
cppcon15.cpp:(.text+0x2cf6): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/cppcon15-4f0a58.o: In function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>, void>::_Async_state_impl(std::_Bind_simple<main::$_0 ()>&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
cppcon15.cpp:(.text+0x6bb6): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to compile with `-pthread` so that the linker lets you make use of async/future/thread functionality.

Comment: @Joshua In `GCC/clang` `-lpthread` is deprecated in favour of `-pthread`.

Comment: @pacevedo, where would that be documented that one could find it w/o first knowing the answer, from undefined reference to `pthread_create'?

Answer (score 1):

For many libraries, you have to include a reference to the library while linking.
For `<future>`, I believe it's `--pthread`.

So try, `clang++ --std=c++14 cppcon15.cpp --pthread`.